# android-maven-plugin and library project

Tags: android, maven

This is pom.xml from my library project.
I do "mvn clean install" and everything is OK. In my local m2 repo I have apklib artifact.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>actionbar</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.markupartist.android</groupId>
    <name>android-actionbar</name>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <platform.version>2.2.1</platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <path>
                            e:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\
                        </path>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This one pom.xml is from my main project which is dependent on above project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.main.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>VirtualRecruiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>MainApp</name>

    <properties>
        <platform.version>2.2.1</platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
            <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>actionbar</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.markupartist.android</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <path>
                            e:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\
                        </path>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

IntelliJ can see my depedency well, but when I run "mvn clean compile" on main project, I have got:
F

> ailed to execute goal on project MainApp: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.main.app:MainApp:apk:1.0: Could not find
>   artifact actionbar:artist.android:apklib:1.0

When I use 'systemPath' and use hardcoded path to my artifact, dependency can be found by maven, but I have compilation error and javac don't see any class from library project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the code you have posted, you made a little mistake maybe it will fix your problem.

You had inverted the `groupId` and `artifactId` on your dependency so Maven can't found it.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>actionbar</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.markupartist.android</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```